# retry same http POST request when error

Tags: angular

## Update:

I have this intercept to intercept my POST request, how can I retry same request when this  request get error status 401 ? How can I wait response of getTicket to return Observable.throw(errore) ?

## UPDATE2

```
return observable.retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors
            .mergeMap((error) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this.getTicket().subscribe((res) => {
                        this.TICKET = res.json().data.ticket
                    })
                    return Observable.of(true)
                }else{
                    return Observable.throw(error)
                }
            })
            .delay(1000)
            .take(2);
    })
```

Comment: 401 means that you must be authenticated to access the resource. Why would retrying help?

Comment: my question is not why 401 but how can retry an request whcih get 401 status, I just want getAnother ticket and retry last request with new ticket... this is internal... please see my updated question